# How can I use dynamically the first frame as poster in mobile HTML5 video?

Tags: html, video, mobile, preload, popcornjs

I have tried for `popcorn.capture.js`and set `preload="auto"`,the first just suits firefox and the next suits pc browser. I want some way to achieve in mobile (Wechat). Could you help me?

Comment: I thought just omitting `poster` all together gives you the first frame as default.>[A URL indicating a poster frame to show until the user plays or seeks. If this attribute isn't specified, nothing is displayed until the first frame is available; then the first frame is shown as the poster frame.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: thanks a lot.It works well on chrome in pc,but doesn't work on mobile.Besides, it seems be related to video coding.I'm exploring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On mobile devices the device will not start to download the video automatically, as you may be aware. This is to avoid the user running up large data bills.

Because the bowser has not downloaded the video it can't extract the first frame to display it, so you need to use the poster mechanism in HTML5 to display an image as the thumbnail.

One common approach is to generate the thumbnail on the server side when you 'ingest' or add the video to the server and save it where it can be served as the video poster.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding autoplay to my video tag and pausing the video on load.

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVideo');
 myVideo.pause(); 
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" autoplay controls> 
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```